# Django non unique field to unique

Tags: python, django, unique

I have the following model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

This code is in production, we saw the need of make this field unique. Like the code below:

```
class Car(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
```

The problem is, there are car names duplicated in production, so when I try to run a South migration I got this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "car_name_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (name)=() is duplicated.
```

I can't change the client's data. How can I turn the non-unique field in an unique field without changing the data?

Or if there is no way to turn this unique field, how can I ensure that new cars will have the unique name?

Comment: It looks like the issue is more of empty values for `name`, than the actual uniqueness.

Comment: This is only one example, if I remove empty values another duplicated values will raise.

Comment: Is there any other identifier which can identify a unique car ? - for example a combination of (car name, car brand), etc...  Names are generally bad candidates for unique identifiers anyways..

Comment: Sorry @karthikr, but there isn't. The name is exactly what we want to be unique.

Comment: in that case, you can have a slug field which generates a unique slug behind the scene in case of duplicates. The disadvantage though, is unless you use the slug, there is no way to differentiate different objects, just by looking at the name.

Comment: This won't solve my problem, the name of a car is set by an user. I can ensure that user's can't add duplicated names.